# Month, Year with Value Plot, Pandas and MatPlotLib

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a time graph with month and year combined for my x and values for y. Python is reading my excel data with decimal points so won't allow to convert to %m %Y. Any ideas?

[MY EXCEL DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R4rS.png)

```
How python reads my data

0     3.0-2015.0
1     5.0-2015.0
3     6.0-2017.0
     ...
68       nan-nan
69       nan-nan
70       nan-nan
71       nan-nan'


# Code

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math

 # Set Directory
workbook1 = 'GAP Insurance - 1.xlsx'
workbook2 = 'GAP Insurance - 2.xlsx'
workbook3 = 'GAP Insurance - 3.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(workbook1, 'Sheet1',)

# Set x axis


df['Time'] = (df['Month']).astype(str)+ '-' + (df['Year']).astype(str)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting to "int" before converting to "str" in this line:

```py
df['Time'] = (df['Month']).astype(str)+ '-' + (df['Year']).astype(str)
```

This should ensure that what gets stored does not include decimal points.

Comment: I get a 'cannot convert float NaN to integer' error

Comment: What you do about this will depend on how you want to handle cases where the month/year has NaNs. Where would you want to plot it on the x-axis? You could for example, as a very first step, replace NaNs with a numeric value that makes sense in the context of your plot. Or exclude those rows entirely from the dataframe/plot.